# Add a break after a row is added in a table

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

Basically I have a table to "post" stuff in and when you click the submit button it adds text to a table, but if you create 2 posts they look like they're attached, but I can't figure out how to add a break in between each row.

Comment: Can you please show your code & html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it a few ways I guess.

I assume you just want to create spacing between the rows or cells?

You could do this with simple css:

```
.rows tr td
{
    padding-bottom:40px;
}
```

or you could amend you function to insert a blank row under each post.

Comment: Thank you man, I used my blank row function, I never thought of that lol.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cellspacing property as well

```
<table cellspacing="20">.....</table>
```